# Does the Armorer Artificer's Lightning Launcher make a sound when attacking?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

Does the Armorer Artificer's Lightning Launcher make a sound when attacking? I just recent aquired Exploring Eberon and saw Silent Weapon Infusion and want to know if it can be applied to it.

> Silent Weapon -Item: A simple or martial ranged weapon - This magic weapon grants a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it. When the wielder is hidden from a creature and misses it with a ranged weapon attack made with this weapon, making the attack doesn’t reveal the wielder’s position.

Comment: Is there a reason you think this infusion cannot be applied?

Comment: The questions "does it make a sound when attacking" and "can this infusion be applied" are separate. It seems to me you want to ask the latter, but the title does ot fit that.

Comment: I retracted my close vote after re-reading. At the corse of the question is whether the Lightning Launcher makes a sound when attacking, and we can clear up any misconceptions about Silent Weapon along the way.

Answer (score 11):

### It doesn't actually matter

The general rule for attacking when hidden, from Unseen Attackers and Targets, says:

> When a creature can't see you, you have advantage on attack rolls against it. If you are hidden--both unseen and unheard--when you make an attack, **you give away your location when the attack hits or misses**.

That's it. You attack and you give away your position.

The infusion simply gives the ability to remain hidden when missing with an attack. Any questions as to whether a weapon is already silent doesn't impact on this at all. It's a moot point as without the infusion you **always** give away your position.

Comment: Why yes, specialy of you're an Assassin & you contradict you ranswer.  Remaining hidden before & after an attack with ranged weapon,  you bet your life you want to not make a sound before and after the attack. So it does matter weather the ranged attack makes a sound. And FYI rea;istically, electricity does make  noise wieather as  ahum based on the voltage,  sparks pops & lightning booms with thunder. You want proof listen to a  Testla coil hum when powerd up. So it makes sense to ask if a "lighting" badsed dmamging weapon make a noise. It;s not  a laser (radiant) that would naturaly quiet.

Comment: @Jhyarelle It *doesn't* matter. Even if the weapon didn't make sound originally, it would still reveal your position whether you hit or miss. Adding the silent weapon infusion simply makes it not reveal your location on a miss; a regularly silent weapon would reveal your location without this infusion

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver It makes exactly the same sound as Iron Man's repulsor blasts and you and your DM aren't allowed to rule otherwise.  But seriously -- "Silent" *must* do more than simply muffle sounds; presumably a lightning blast is a big, bright, obvious thing that would visually give you away even if it were dead silent.  The name of the infusion is for flavor, it doesn't define the effect of the infusion.